# iPhone position of a subview?

Tags: iphone, position, subview

I add a view dynamically, but when it appears on the form, it's in the upper left hand corner.

Where do I set the X and Y of the new subview?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should set the frame property:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,200,100);
```

This will position the view at location (10,10), with a size of 200x100

Answer (score 3):

Agreed. 
Note that you cannot change coordinates individually, as you might expect. That is, this doesn't work:

```
self.mysubview.frame.origin.x += 17;   // FAILS! Not assignable!!
```

If it was a pain to calculate all the other coordinates you need, you can (a) suck it up or (b) do something like the following:

```
CGRect theFrame = self.mysubview.frame;
theFrame.origin.x += 17;
self.mysubview.frame = theFrame;  // this is legal
```